# Creating a data.frame with piping in R - and naming columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I know I can do this in other ways, but I am just curious.

```
dfDice = sample(1:6, 10000, replace = TRUE) %>%
            data.frame()
```

The above creates a data.frame, where the column header is called '.'.

So my first question is can I pipe the column header into my code? I have tried putting it in my data.frame() function but it just creates a new column.

And my second question is, can I pipe multiple columns into a data.frame, or would I have to do something like this?:

```
dfDice = (num = sample(1:6, 10000, replace = TRUE) %>% 
              data.frame(letters = sample(LETTERS, 10000, replace = TRUE))
```

Again, I know this is not the best way to create a data.frame, I am just curious from a learning perspective and trying to fully understand piping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my first question is can I pipe the column header into my code? I
>   have tried putting it in my data.frame() function but it just creates
>   a new column.

For single columns you have two options:

```
dfDice <- sample(1:6, 10000, replace = TRUE) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNnames("num")

dfDice <- sample(1:6, 10000, replace = TRUE) %>%
  data.frame(num = .)
```

> And my second question is, can I pipe multiple columns into a
>   data.frame?

```
sample(1:6, 5, replace = TRUE) %>% 
  cbind(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c("num", "letters"))
```

Comment: Perfect, your response is very helpful and clear. I can just keep on using cbind to add additional columns. Great! Thank you

Comment: I couldnt get 'set_colnames' to work, but 'setNames' did the trick. Thank you again

Comment: I always assumed `set_colnames` is from base, it's actually from magrittr but put in namespace base

Answer (score 2):

To assign names, you can use a predefined vector and use `setNames`

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- "a"

sample(1:6, 10, replace = TRUE) %>%
   data.frame()  %>%
   setNames(cols)
```

Or can also name dynamically without knowing number of columns beforehand.

```
sample(1:6, 10, replace = TRUE) %>%
  data.frame()  %>%
  setNames(letters[seq_along(.)])
```

For 2nd question simplest option would be

```
data.frame(a = sample(1:6, 10, replace = TRUE), 
           b = sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

OR if you want to use piping maybe ?

```
sample(1:6, 10, replace = TRUE) %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(cols) %>%
  bind_cols(b = sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE))
```